Streaming Microsoft Outlook from Windows to Linux
I migrate from Windows to Linux but have to continue to use Microsoft Outlook. I do not trust the reliability of Wine and do not want to use a web UI. An interesting possibility would be to run Outlook in a Linux-hosted Windows VM. A workable UX would however require Outlook to appear on the Linux desktop without an RDP window around it. This is sometimes called "application streaming" or "seamless mode". I know that Windows Server comes with Remote Desktop Services (RDS) that supposedly can be used in a RemoteApp mode. What should I do to publish Outlook as a RemoteApp and consume it on Linux?

Outlook for on-prem Exchange or for 365? If it's for 365 why not use https://outlook.office.com/ ?

Why do you need to use Outlook? If this is because the backend is Exchange, then you should be able to connect to it using any client which supports imap4.

@BobGoddard as long as your Exchange account is not restricted to MAPI only.

@BobGoddard and honestly, thunderbird, still the fullest-featured mail client for linux, is decades behind outlook when it comes to real-life day-to-day office things like handling calendar invites. Evolution is kind of nice, but still, 20 years into development, really awkward to use if you're not used to 1997's email clients. I hate it, but I can fully appreciate why someone would want "outlook" and not "outlook-compatible".

I would strongly recommend giving Crossover [Office] a try. Will save you 50 GB of disk space and the need to keep maintenance for an extra OS. It will also work faster and will behave and look better. Seamless Window mode in VirtualBox and VMWare Workstation is quite buggy.

@ChrisDavies. This will be either permanently licensed or 365 Outlook, used mostly for Outlook.com accounts configured as Exchange. As I stated, I do not want to use a web interface (never got to like it) and am looking for a desktop client solution.
I need Calendar support, and IMAP does not do this.
I also need the Reminders Outlook window, my life is organized around it. AFAIK the only Linux email client currently supporting Exchange is Evolution, and I don't think it has the Reminders window.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov I checked the Crossover website, and it states that Outlook does not run on it.

Indeed. Then using a VM or a remote desktop could be the only solution.

If you have free choice of virtualizer, virtual box comes with the guest extensions that allow VM windows to behave as if they were native.

I never used VirtualBox, and am concerned that for a Linux novice, setting it up together with guest extensions etc. may be overwhelming. My plan has been to install Windows Server on the most user-friendly Linux hypervisor and figure out how to access Outlook running on that VM.

that is pretty much the most user-friendly hypervisor.
